# How can Text Input of PowerApps add its value to sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

In PowerApps I have created a return book screen and there is a extent book function as a button where we have to apply a logic and the value of the extended book value is not getting add in sharepoint list which is a (backend).
I have to add a value of extended no of books to the sharepoint list after clicking a button which is in PoweraApps?
How can it be Done?

I tried a
Patch function Formula,
Set function,
Update and Update IF function (formulas from PowerApps)
but the number which I want to add is not getting add ?

I want that no to be added in sharepoint list, but the source is  PowerApps.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details, such as the exact formulas you tried, results (if there was an error message, etc.). Also check permissions on the list, field settings (e.g. max length of input). I also recommend the Monitor tool in Power Apps studio, check the traffic between your app and SharePoint in detail.